# Source package contains file with errors

Tags: java, netbeans

As you can see from the screenshot below, netbeans reports that the 'Source package contains one or more files with errors'. However, whilst there are red exclamation marks next to 'ODESolver' and 'Source Packages' to make this clear, there is no such exclamation mark by any of the folders or files in Source Packages, as one might expect, so I have no idea which file is supposed to contain errors. Can anyone shed some light on this?

[image: netBeans error]

Comment: Can you print the top 10 lines of the error?

Comment: It's always a good idea to use text and a good description, rather than a screenshot, when you can. Keep that in mind and as jaesanx said, add the text instead. (For instance, I can't load your screenshot, so I can't help as is)

Comment: Actually, the program compiles now (so no need to copy the first 10 lines of the error anymore, as there's no longer an error to copy)- I've solved that problem- it was because I needed to include the jar files rather than folders containing them  in the classpath. However, i still get 'Source package contains one or more files with errors' and the red exclamation marks as shown in the screenshot.